# JSON Decode Error when requesting JSON response from Google

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to get my head around the requests python package

```
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=london"

response = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept": "application/json"})

data = response.json()
```

And i'm receiving the following error:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

However this code does work with some other websites.. is there a reason this would error on specific websites and is there a way around it? For example if i wanted the search results when searching London on Google?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response.json()` does not convert any server response to a JSON, it simply parses 'stringified' JSONs. So if the server returns a string that is not a JSON, then this will throw a decode error.

Some servers do return JSON objects, in which case your code will work. In the case of `https://www.google.com/search?q=london` this actually returns HTML code (as you would expect since it's a webpage).

You can test this by printing the response:

```py
print(response.text)
```

which outputs:

```
# some very long output that ends with:
...();})();google.drty&&google.drty();</script></body></html>
```

Notice the `</html>` tag at the end? So this cannot be parsed into a JSON.

So how do you parse this into a usable HTML? You can use beautiful soup:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=london"

response = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept": "application/json"})

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, however i'm getting the below error when running it with the fix:

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Oops, I meant `response.text`. Made the fix.